When Installing LyX "No textclass is found" message popped when first launching it, how to solve?
I downloaded LyX and TEXlive from the manual in Hebrew, it uses a script to download everything automatically for Hebrew users, (if it helps anyone here's the Hebrew manual it's completely in Hebrew, the automatic download is on page 4 of this file).
I'll now present the chronological order of what happened:

I used the script of that manual to automatically download lyx and texlive.
when it finished I opened LyX and found out their script downloads LyX version 2.3.7 when I wanted the most recent 2.4.2 (important to mention LyX works just fine at this moment!)
I deleted LyX alone.
I downloaded LyX 2.4.2 from the official website, in the exact way the manual explains in the manual way. (the path is C:\texlive\2024\bin\windows)
when I tried to launch I got the following message:

I pressed "reconfigure" and then in lyx "reconfigure" again, and restarted LyX but this pop-up still came up.

I'm downloading it on Windows 10 Home, I already posted on the Hebrew support Facebook group but the post is awaiting approval so I'm trying my luck here, please tell me if you need any more information to help me

How does Help->About LyX says about the user directory?
It may be pointing to the one of the old version. Deleting it and reconfiguring LyX may help.

at the end i decided to delete and reinstall everything, it works as intended now, I guess the automatic script is broken now
